# Anylogic CompareRuns does not execute Main Agent

Tags: gis, simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling, statechart

I am working on an agent-based model and now I'm trying to experiment with CompareRuns.

when I execute the experiment, it should simulate the model several times and after each simulation, a dataset of sample data should be filled. 
there is also a state chart in Main agent and each state has a `traceln("...")`. so after passing through each state, something must be printed.

the problem is that neither the print commands return anything, nor the dataset in which I store my data returns anything but zeros.

P.S.: I also have a GIS map in my model. could that be the reason for misbehaving of Anylogic?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and fixed it. 
check and double check all the "Parameter"s in the Main agent and make sure they all have different names and labels. the problem was that two parameters had same labels and it messed up the whole experiment. 

I fixed the labels and the default value of all parameters, deleted the CompareRun experiment, made a new one and it worked.

Comment: yeah... that happens when we copy paste variables.. they keep the same labels. very dangerous